# sqlcmd slow against SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

I am trying to import a longish SQL script (3.5 millions of lines, 1,5 GB in size) containing mainly short INSERT INTO statements with data using `sqlcmd -E -d <database> -S 127.0.0.1 -i <scriptfile>` and it is nearly crawling to a halt (approximatly 150 lines per second) without inferring any noticeable load on the SQL server host (all CPU cores are nearly idle, Disk throughput is at around 200 KB/s).

As the source file is located on an NFS share, I first suspected this to be the culprit, but an identical script available locally runs at just the same speed.

The database is basically empty, the tables are created by the very same script, no triggers or other fancyness - just the raw, mainly numeric or varchar data.

What is SQLCMD waiting for? Is there any way to speed it up?

### Edit:

we are limited in our means to alter the data in the SQL script files. The data is provided by a third party for an import procedure. I believe it was originally exported using Management Studio 2005 "Script table as..." feature.

Editing the file is tedious due to sheer size - any operation takes forever with common text editors, although prepending a "SET NOCOUNT ON" was done by copying two files together - and it brought a speedup of approximately 50%.

Due to the text encoding (Unicode-LE) it is impossible to edit with the common set of GNU textutils (which would otherwise work fine with large files) without converting - and I am reluctant to converting because of data fidelity issues which are likely to come with it.

So I am somewhat stuck with how to apply the suggestions on inserting the BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT TRAN blocks or converting the individual inserts into larger sets.

Comment: You could pull out most of the insert commands into a separate file and `BULK INSERT` it.  Or do you have tangled dependencies and foreign keys to satisfy?

Comment: Can you push some requirements back to the 3rd party vendor? Even they should realize that what they're providing you is not practical. Feel free to point them here. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Inject some `GO` commands every thousand or few thousand lines. Then instead of one ginormous batch it is broken up into multiple batches.
- <strike>Change your individual `INSERT` statements to `INSERT ... VALUES ()` with a thousand sets each.</strike>
- Use transactions and commit and/or checkpoint gratuitously (again, every 1000 inserts or so is probably a good place to start, in combination with `GO`). Your watch and the log will thank you.
- It's a silly trivial little thing, but make sure your script has `SET NOCOUNT ON` - otherwise the UI, SQL Server, and the network in between spend a lot of time sending `1 row(s) affected` messages back and forth for every single insert.
- Best is probably to use [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or maybe even [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026%28SQL.100%29.aspx) instead of Management Studio. Part of the problem is probably the memory overhead on your own machine just loading that huge file, never mind trying to parse/execute it. I'd be curious to see private bytes for ssms.exe while this is going on...
- Based on offline discussion with the OP, adding another option: ask the vendor for a backup instead of a script. Then you can restore that to some test or dummy system, and generate inserts from that manually (or use import/export, or Red Gate's data compare tool). This may end up being net same amount of time, but won't kill the log with that huge script of millions of inserts...

Comment: +1 - This is the second-least-efficient way of loading 3.5m rows.  The only thing worse I can think of would be to load it from XML

Comment: @JNK or 3.5 million individual one-line text files

Comment: I'm *not* supposed to be using 3.5 million individual one line text files?

Comment: Well, only if you want the process to take all week so you can fill your timesheet while you were playing Draw Something instead...

Comment: I *am* filling my timesheet, but I have a bad conscience about it, so instead of playing Draw Something I am posting to Stack Exchange. I am having problems editing the file(s) - see my edit. Any tips?

Comment: @syneticon-dj yes I added a comment after your edit to push back to the vendor. Just because they're giving you garbage doesn't mean you have to swallow it. I will suggest though that when I say "edit the file" I don't necessarily mean you open it in notepad and bring your workstation to its knees. You can easily write a C# or other command-line program which should have a much easier time modifying the file and presenting you with something more usable. Take the first 500 and last 500 lines of one of your files, work with that, and see where it gets you. Vendor pushback is top choice though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am not that familiar with C# - any code samples? The involved functions should be able to read a file line-wise and it would be great if they would be able to cope with long lines - we also have 100 GB of other files with Hexadecimal-coded BLOB inserts which probably would need editing as well. Pushing it back would be difficult without concise directions on what to do - can Management Studio be made to script tables with data more efficiently?

Comment: @syneticon-dj You can use powershell for this (which could be considered .NET or C# lite) - the advantage to .NET is it will read/modify the source file in a stream instead of as a chunk, which makes it manageable.  [This is a good starter post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783837/find-and-replace-in-a-large-file) on SO.

Comment: Regarding your second point. Have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values).

Comment: @Mikael interesting I had been under the same impression as that OP...

Comment: Optimal would be to add `1000 /  colcount` rows in one insert.

Comment: I wonder why I had 1000 absolute in my head as opposed to 1000 / column count...

Comment: @syneticon-dj what about [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) to replace `\r\n` with `;\r\nGO\r\n`. That way you're not extracting any of the data, but you're batching one line. You can also skip `n` lines with sed.

Comment: @syneticon-dj here's something that will inject "GO" every 10000th line. you can paste this into notepad ... save as [filename].cs and then csc to compile it. https://gist.github.com/2852756

Comment: @swasheck my input data is unicode - sed won't cope with it all that well. Thanks for the code link. BTW: I've asked for a database backup instead, let's see if it turns up.